# How to avoid to duplicate a jpa mapping (entity, service, repository..) if same table but different schemas?

Tags: java, jpa, mapping

I am using jpa and have 2 entities, but in this situation :

Entity A = schemaA.tableX
Entity B = schemaB.tableX

tableX is the same but duplicated on 2 different schemas (A and B), same columns inside, and I am supposed to fill them with same data through my application.

The question is : is it possible in my code, to mappe once this tableX and somehow, data will be splited on two, one for each schema ??

I do not want :

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "TableX", schema = "A")
public class A implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private String id; <=== on table A
 }
```

And :

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "TableX", schema = "B")
public class B implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private String id; <=== on table B
 }
```

A dumb copy/past of : entity, repository, service, impl... because exactelly the same Table !

Answer (score 1):

You could do that probably with a `@MappedSuperClass`:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperClass // <-- see this annotation
public class AbstractTable implements Serializable { // <-- name the class however you want
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
}
```

And then change your two other classes to this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableX", schema = "A")
public class A extends AbstractTable {}
```

And

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableX", schema = "B")
public class B extends AbstractTable {}
```